# lookup in two files with xslt for index of a book

Tags: xml, xslt, latex

I try to set a book with TeX based on an XML file. I am a newbie in XML/XSLT and don't manage to get the index-output to work: I have one file with the names of the persons and one with the titles of the artworks.

My source-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<text>I am a fan of <persName key="A01">Will Shakespeare</persName> and I really do like <workName key="W02">Hamlet</workName>.</text>
```

combined with person.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <number>A01</number>
        <name>Shakespeare, William</name>
        <born>1564</born>
        <died>1616</died>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>A02</number>
        <name>Marlowe, Christopher</name>
        <born>1564</born>
        <died>1615</died>
    </row>
</root>
```

and the file work.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wroot>
    <row>
        <worknumber>W01</worknumber>
        <title>Romeo and Juliet</title>
        <author>A01</author>
    </row>
    <row>
        <worknumber>W02</worknumber>
        <title>Hamlet</title>
        <author>A01</author>
    </row>
</wroot>
```

and applied with this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="person-top" select="document('person.xml')/root"/>
    <xsl:variable name="work-top" select="document('work.xml')/wroot"/>
    <xsl:key name="person-lookup" match="row" use="number"/>
    <xsl:key name="work-lookup" match="row" use="worknumber"/>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="persName">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$person-top">
            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="workName">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$work-top">
            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:param name="curr-label"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('person-lookup', $curr-label/@key)/name"/>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="wroot">
        <xsl:param name="curr-label"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('work-lookup', $curr-label/@key)/title"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs (correctly):
I am a fan of Will Shakespeare\index{Shakespeare, William} and I really do like Hamlet\index{Hamlet}.

But to get Hamlet to show as a child of Shakespeare in the TeX-index I have to achieve this kind of index-entry for works:

\index{Shakespeare, William!Hamlet}

So in the workName-template it should lookup the person-template and use the author-key. Can you help me to achieve that?

Thanks! Martin

P.S. I somehow think I could solve my problem by dividing it into two steps, where the first is to create a new work2.xml where an xslt fills in all the names of the persons, but this seems tedious and unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be much simpler - if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:param name="persons" select="document('person.xml')"/>
<xsl:param name="works" select="document('work.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="person-lookup" match="row" use="number"/>
<xsl:key name="work-lookup" match="row" use="worknumber"/>

<xsl:template match="persName">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('person-lookup', @key, $persons)/name"/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workName">
    <xsl:variable name="work-entry" select="key('work-lookup', @key, $works)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('person-lookup', $work-entry/author, $persons)/name"/>
    <xsl:text>!</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$work-entry/title"/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
I am a fan of Will Shakespeare\index{Shakespeare, William} and I really do like Hamlet\index{Shakespeare, William!Hamlet}.
```

Note the use of the third argument in the `key()` function.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question: Say, e.g., i would put the Title in italics in my work.xml-file: <title><hi rend="italics">Hamlet</hi></title> the wrapping element <hi> does not get passed on. (I know this makes no sense here, but it does in the actual working file.) How can I achieve that?

Comment: @martinanton Without testing: you would have to change the output method to `xml` and use `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:value-of` when fetching the node.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using predicates rather than key-mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="person-top" select="document('person.xml')/root"/>
    <xsl:variable name="work-top" select="document('work.xml')/wroot"/>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="workName">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="pname" select="../persName/@key" />
        <xsl:variable name="wname" select="@key" />
        <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$person-top/row[number=$pname]/name" />
        <xsl:text>!</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$work-top/row[worknumber=$wname]/title"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does descent one level(../) from the current workName-Node to get the persName-Node.

Comment: This will not work when text contains multiple/mixed references. Try, for example: `<text>I am a fan of <persName key="A02">Marlowe</persName> and I really do like <workName key="W02">Hamlet</workName>.</text>`.

Comment: Well, no. I did think about modifying my solution to adapt to your objections but refrained from doing so. Ex falsum quod libet. Wrong input data -> wrong output data. Assuming that Marlowe is not considered to be a possible author of Hamlet: that is wrong input - not wrong algorithm. Otherwise some information would be omitted and would be redundant.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. The input is text, and I see no reason why it could not contain any number of references to any number of authors and/or works, in any order. If the author chooses to write "*Marlowe[A02] is no Shakespeare [A01] and he did not write Hamlet[W02]*", the lookup should still follow the supplied reference numbers - and only these.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) I had really misunderstood the exact task. Thanks for clarifying.